# Wifi Adapter doesn't work in 20.04

Tags: wireless

I moved to Ubuntu 20.04 and my realtek 8188EE doesn't work, I can't event ping to my router, but when I ping to myself works. I tried with another adapter and this another one works ok.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt install build-essential linux-headers-generic git dkms

git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git

cd rtlwifi_new

make

sudo make install

sudo modprobe -v rtl8188ee

Reboot
```

Hope this helps.